# How to resolve DataSource Error in Spring Application?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I am running into a "Unable to set value for property driver-class-name" (see last segment for full error details). I've read several other articles on SO that seem to suggest I have this set up correctly, but I can't figure out what I am missing so I apologize in advance since using a properties file is new to me. What is causing this error?

application.properties:

```
# MySQL
db.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cafe?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
db.user=root
db.password=root
```

pom.xml:

```
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.22</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

DataSource config:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("../../../../../../../../application.properties")
public class DBConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("db.driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("db.url");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("db.user");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("db.password");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
10:58:11.577 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - Driver class db.driver not found in Thread context class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2, trying classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
10:58:11.580 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - Failed to load driver class db.driver from HikariConfig class classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindError(Binder.java:363)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:323)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:238)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:212)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.bind(DataSourceBuilder.java:94)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:75)
    at edu.bu.met.cs665.database.DataConfig.getDataSource(DataConfig.java:22)
    at edu.bu.met.cs665.database.CreateConnection.<init>(CreateConnection.java:26)
    at edu.bu.met.cs665.database.CreateConnection.getInstance(CreateConnection.java:35)
    at edu.bu.met.cs665.Main.seedDatabase(Main.java:51)
    at edu.bu.met.cs665.Main.main(Main.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to set value for property driver-class-name
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$BeanProperty.setValue(JavaBeanBinder.java:351)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:451)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:571)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:557)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.access$300(Binder.java:512)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:449)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:390)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:319)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$BeanProperty.setValue(JavaBeanBinder.java:348)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class db.driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:486)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load driver class
> db.driver

This means that `dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("db.driver");` pass as value the `db.driver` and not the value `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

You need to read the value of those configuration properties. As you have it right now it passes as values the property names of those fields. The following should work for you

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("../../../../../../../../application.properties")
public class DBConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource()
    {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
        dataSourceBuilder.url(env.getProperty("db.url"));
        dataSourceBuilder.username(env.getProperty("db.user"));
        dataSourceBuilder.password(env.getProperty("db.password"));
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `spring-boot` so application.properties should follow standard and you don't need to define any DB configuration like DBConfig.java

Here is detail how your `application.properties` look like https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/